# Profile matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django

Hi have getting error of Profile matching query does not exist and here is my code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yA3Nd.jpg)

Hi have getting error of Profile matching query does not exist and here is my code[enter image description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the User Object.

You can as well try this:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
profile = user.profile.filter().first()
```

Then in your model class, add `related_field="profile"` to the user ForiegnKey field.

This Approach is called Database Relationship.

Or You can do it this way.

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
```

This will give you what you want.

Comment: I could not understand

Comment: I can see in your Model Class that the user has a foreign key on the profile table.  So if you want to go by the first option, You don't need to call the Profile model class again because since there's a relationship between the user and profile, you can then access profile data using the user instance. For the second option,  you get the user objects and use the user instance to get the id `user.id` and since the user is a relationship field on the profile table, it will be named `user_id`. You can then pass the user.id to use it to get it.